# Julia Package has "no known versions!" when trying to add a package

Tags: julia

I am getting an error when I try to add a package in Julia. It is saying the package I am trying to add has "no known versions!". What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue when you lose connection to the Julia Registry (which is where packages are pulled from). You can first type `]` to enter pkg mode in the Julia Repl and then do the following:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> registry remove General
   Removing registry `General` from ~/.julia/registries/General

(@v1.5) pkg> registry add https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git
    Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
      Added registry `General` to `~/.julia/registries/General`
```

Try to add the Package again and the issue should be resolved.